# WPF ContextMenu complex item stays open on click?

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

So I have a complex context menu. It doesn't have just menuitems. It has radio buttons as well, and a stackpanel on the bottom which has an integerupdown box.

[image: contextmenu]

```
<Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <RadioButton Tag="30" Content="30 seconds" GroupName="adLength" Checked="adLength_Checked" IsChecked="True"/>
        <RadioButton Tag="60" Content="1 minutes" GroupName="adLength" Checked="adLength_Checked"/>
        <RadioButton Tag="90" Content="1 min 30 sec" GroupName="adLength" Checked="adLength_Checked"/>
        <RadioButton Tag="120" Content="2 minutes" GroupName="adLength" Checked="adLength_Checked"/>
        <RadioButton Tag="150" Content="2 min 30 sec" GroupName="adLength" Checked="adLength_Checked"/>
        <RadioButton Tag="180" Content="3 minutes" GroupName="adLength" Checked="adLength_Checked"/>
        <Separator/>
        <MenuItem x:Name="advert_Auto" Header="Run Automatically" IsCheckable="true" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock>every</TextBlock>
            <xctk:IntegerUpDown x:Name="advert_Time" Value="30" Minimum="15" Width="50" Margin="5,0" />
            <TextBlock>min</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ContextMenu>
</Button.ContextMenu>
```

The `<MenuItem>` object has the option for `staysopenonclick`; when someone clicks on that item, the context menu stays open. The `<RadioButton>` objects don't have that option, but they stay open anyways.

The issue I am having is with the last item, the `<StackPanel>`. When the user clicks on the text area of the `IntegerUpDown`, the context menu closes. It makes it pretty impossible to use the item as is. Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do in a context menu? Is there a way to keep the context menu open until the user clicks outside of the menu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just stuff the `StackPanel` in a `MenuItem` as its header and set the `StaysOpenOnClick` property to `true`.

```
<MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="True">
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock>every</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Text="30" Width="50" Margin="5,0" />
            <TextBlock>min</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```